# Modifying the CSS of a template of a component in another component

Tags: angular

I am calling component A as a child-component in component B. Component A has a `div` class containing CSS that I need to modify in Component B. How do I access that `div` class from component B?

Template of component A:

```
    <div class="something">
    .
    .

    </div>
```

Template of component B:

```
<app-componentA></app-componentA>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really do that, you can have an input of the styles/classes you want applied for the child component, however if you need to do it, you can use ngdeep (deprecated) [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

**EDIT**

You can pass an input (which indeed is just a JavaScript object) from the parent component, and assign that dynamically in the child component like that:

Child component:

```
<div [ngStyle]="inputStyle">
</div>
```

And its TS:

```
@Input() inputStyle; //This is the input received from the parent component
```

Then in the parent component, you can pass the CSS as a JavaScript object normally like the following :

```
<app-componentA [inputStyle]="{backgroundColor: 'red', 'height': '100px'}"></app-componentA>
```

This example sets the style to a static styles object passed through the HTML, of course this can be used with dynamic object (that you assign through the parent's TS file), or you can even pass custom class names using the same concept but using `ngClass` instead of `ngStyle` in the child component

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the first part? I would like to know how to have an input of the styles. From what I googled, input output only seems to apply to javascript variables.

Comment: like: <app-componentA [variable]="value"></app-componentA>

Comment: How do I do it for CSS?

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer

Comment: You can do what you want with SCSS using @mixins or functions

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20844525)

Comment: @xploshioOn 
Sorry, I was away, it is indeed an answer, ::ng-deep does exactly what he wants to achieve, I just edited my answer to show the alternative (should have done so from the start tbh :\)

Comment: @abdullahkady it has worked! Thank you so much for the detailed explanation.